# What commands accept and/or return RESP3 boolean values?

Tags: redis

I'd like to add boolean support to my Redis parser. Which command/s accept and/or return RESP3 boolean values (`#t\r\n` or `#f\r\n` as [documented](https://github.com/redis/redis-specifications/blob/master/protocol/RESP3.md)?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
EVAL "redis.setresp(3); return true" 0
```